# Getting a redirect on webpage when using file_get_contents()

Tags: php, dom, metadata

I recently purchased the WS-1400-IP weather station from Ambient Weather that links up to Weather Underground. I am attempting to do a DOM query on the HTML of the IP link device. Here is my code:

(I know its very crude code, it's just a preliminary thing).

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$filename = "http://10.175.3.28/bscsetting.htm";
$html = file_get_contents($filename);
echo "<input type=text value='{$html}'></input>";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$x = new DOMXPath($dom); 
$data = array();
foreach($x->query("//input") as $node) 
{
    $data[][$node->getAttribute("name")] = $node->getAttribute("value");
} 
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

And this is what I am seeing when I echo the HTML I am getting from the device:

```
<input type=text value='ction: Keep-Alive
Content-type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=big5">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=./bscsetting.htm">
<title></title>
<body leftmargin="80" topmargin="80" marginwidth="80" marginheight="0" bgcolor="#333">
<font size="+3"><strong><p align="center"></p></strong></font>
</body>
</html>
'></input>[

]
```

And here is what I should be seeing (as this is what I see when I use a regular browser):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>LiveData</title>
        <link href="axcss0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="800" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="right" bgcolor="#0088F7">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="20" height = "80">&nbsp;</td>                                             
                            <td ><img src="img/1.jpg" width="74" height="80" ></td>
                            <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="txtstyle_1" >ambient weather observerIP 2.0 </td>                                   
                        </tr>
                </table></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="2" align="right" bgcolor="#60B7FF"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="120" align="center"><font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><em>Version:2.0.0</em></font></td>
                        </tr>
                </table></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="left" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
                    <table width="20" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><div class="menuitem_1"><a href="bscsetting.htm">Local Network</a></div></td>
                            <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><div class="menuitem_1"><a href="weather.htm">Weather Network</a></div></td>
                            <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><div class="menuitem_1"><a href="station.htm">Station Settings</a></div></td>
                            <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="menuitem_1"><a href="livedata.htm">Live Data</a></div></td>
                            <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><div class="menuitem_1"><a href="correction.htm">Calibration</a></div></td>     
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <form name="livedata" method="POST" onsubmit="return chkForm(0);">  

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="subitem_1">Live Data</div></td>
                </tr>   
                 <tr>
                    <td width="533" bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Receiver Time:</div></td>
                    <td width="307" bgcolor="#EDEFEF">
                    <input name="CurrTime" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 120px" value="16:34 03/04/2015" maxlength="16"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="533" bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Indoor Sensor ID</div></td>
                    <td width="307" bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="IndoorID" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="0x19" maxlength="4" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Outdoor Sensor1 ID</div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="Outdoor1ID" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="0x94" maxlength="4" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Outdoor Sensor2 ID</div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="Outdoor2ID" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="0x--" maxlength="4" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Indoor Temperature</div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="inTemp" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="71.2" maxlength="5" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Indoor Humidity</div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="inHumi" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="48" maxlength="3" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Absolute Pressure </div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="AbsPress" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="29.23" maxlength="6" /></td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Relative Pressure </div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="RelPress" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="30.29" maxlength="6" /></td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Outdoor Temperature</div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="outTemp" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="34.2" maxlength="5" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Outdoor Humidity </div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="outHumi" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="97" maxlength="3" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Wind Direction </div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="windir" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="228" maxlength="5" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Wind Speed </div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="avgwind" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="10.3" maxlength="5" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Wind Gust </div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="gustspeed" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="12.3" maxlength="5" /></td>
                </tr>         
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Solar Radiation </div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="solarrad" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="17.30" maxlength="12" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">UV </div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="uv" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="68" maxlength="12"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">UVI </div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="uvi" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="0" maxlength="2"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Hourly Rain Rate</div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="rainofhourly" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="0.07" maxlength="7" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Daily Rain</div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="rainofdaily" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="1.81" maxlength="7" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Weekly Rain</div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="rainofweekly" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="2.10" maxlength="7" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Monthly Rain</div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="rainofmonthly" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="2.10" maxlength="7" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><div class="item_1">Yearly Rain</div></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#EDEFEF"><input name="rainofyearly" disabled="disabled" type="text" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 80px" value="2.10" maxlength="7" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#EDEFEF">&nbsp;</td>  
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#EDEFEF">
                        <input name="rain_Default" type="button" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 110px; HEIGHT: 24px;"  onclick="raindef()" value="Rain Reset">
                        <input  id="refresh_st" type="button" class="item_4" style="WIDTH: 110px; HEIGHT: 24px;"  onclick="uiCtrl(this.value);" value="Refresh" />
                        <input  id="refresh_sp" type="button" class="item_2" style="WIDTH: 110px; HEIGHT: 24px;"  onclick="uiCtrl(this.value);" value="Stop Refresh"  />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </form>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#EDEFEF">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

<script src="axjs0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            var rfTaskRuningFlag = 0, rfTimeId;
            uiCtrl('Refresh');

            function uiCtrl(uiCmd)
            {
                if (uiCmd=='Refresh'){
                    document.getElementById('refresh_st').disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById('refresh_sp').disabled = false;
                    rfTaskRuningFlag = 1;
                    rfTaskState = 0;
                    rfTimeId = setInterval("ss()",8000);
                }else if (uiCmd=='Stop Refresh'){
                    document.getElementById('refresh_st').disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById('refresh_sp').disabled = true;
                    rfTaskRuningFlag = 0;
                    clearInterval(rfTimeId);
                }
            }

            function ss()
            {
                if (rfTaskRuningFlag)
                {
                    window.top.location.reload();
                }
            }
            //-->
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I get past the meta refresh? Any ideas?

EDIT: After trying curl, it works as expected.. Why would it make a difference?

Comment: Is the API in the device you have purchased, or a remote server that your device connects to? (I've not heard of Weather Underground, so it may be worth phrasing the question as if nobody does).

Comment: Why are you printing `$html` in an `<input>` element? At the very least you'd have to escape any apostrophes in the HTML, otherwise they will break your outer element anyway.

Comment: @halfer the API is irrelevant to the answer because I am unable to use the API due to cost. I am trying to breakdown the HTML of the device that reports to weather underground (the code above). Since I was getting 0 DOM query results, I was simply echoing the HTML to see what the HTML was that I was pulling.

Comment: OK. I've removed it then - if I found it confusing, others will. You've explained what you are getting, why you do you believe you should be seeing something different? Where did you get that second HTML block from?

Comment: @halfer I should be seeing the large html block. That's what u see when I visit it with the browser. And that's the code I want to breakdown. But when I use file get contents I get the same meta refresh instead no matter what page on the device I try to fetch.

Comment: Just parse the first file with DOMDocument, get the `<meta>` tag, determine where that wants to go, and load that. Repeat until there is no refresh meta tag.

Comment: Try using `curl` instead of file_

Comment: @halfer Thats the problem... If you notice I am trying to grab the url "bscsetting.htm" and when I do, it tries to redirect to "bscsetting.htm". I will try CURL and see if that makes a difference..

Comment: @prodigitalson So curl works.. Why would that make a difference?

Comment: Because `cURL` functions like a normal http client... can sends/receive headers, respects response codes and response headers, etc. I don't know what `CURLOPTs` and values you used so its hard to guess what the key difference is that allowed it to work. As a general rule though when doing this kind of thing I always use and recommend that other's use `cURL` if for know other reason than the ability to handle errors with more detail then just success/fail.

Comment: @prodigitalson feel free to add that as a answer and I will mark it as an answer..

Answer (score 1):

They have an API and use JSON with RESTful protocol.  You need to send your api key in your request to authenticate your server with their’s.  It’s all free and can then specify what data you’re looking for both past and present. You can then display on your webpage or save to your database

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the time (5 years ago), they didn't have this service and I was referring connecting directly to my "hub device" or whatever its called these days (I dont currently have one anymore). Glad to hear they finally got an API.